# Finding if a varchar2 column contains any 10 digit number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I need to find in oracle 9i, rows having a varchar2 column which contains a 10 digit number inside the text.

> eg "some characters aftuivhe 7524941842 some more characters "

The 10 digit number can be any where within text.

Comment: does the text contain characters like @ or $ etc

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

For Oracle 9i

```
WITH TEST
    AS (SELECT
             'some characters aftuivhe 7524941842 some more characters' BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'some characters aftuivhe 1234567890 some more 1234567890 characters'
                 BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '7524941842 some characters aftuivhe  some more characters'
                 BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'characters some characters aftuivhe  some more 7524941842 '
                 BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      SUBSTR (
             TRIM (
                   TRANSLATE (
                            BRNO,
                            '0abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                            '0' ) ),
             0,
             10 )
FROM
      TEST
```

For Oracle 10G and above

```
WITH TEST
    AS (SELECT
             'some characters aftuivhe 7524941842 some more characters' BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'some characters aftuivhe 1234567890 some more characters' BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '7524941842 some characters aftuivhe  some more characters'
                 BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'characters some characters aftuivhe  some more 7524941842 '
                 BRNO
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( BRNO,
                   '[[:digit:]]{10}' ) AS RESULT
FROM
      TEST
WHERE
      REGEXP_LIKE ( BRNO,
                 '[[:digit:]]' );


RESULT
7524941842
1234567890
7524941842
7524941842
```

Comment: I started to write a `regexp_like` answer, but the question states (not very clearly!) that it's for 9i, and that wasn't added until 10g. (Don't you need the `{10}` in the `where` clause too though?)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT LENGTH(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(lower('aftuivhe 7524941842'),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',' '),' ',''))
FROM  dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below approach if there are any characters other the 10 digit number (a,b,C,&,%,$,# etc)in the string.

Assuming there is only one ten digit number and no other numbers.The logic is to filter the characters which are not numbers and then replace them with Blank

The example with [Sql fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/19001/0)

```
select  translate('etdgdb @# 1234567890 kgmn wwjw',
'A'||translate('etdgdb @# 1234567890 kgmn wwjw','A1234567890','A')
,'A')
 from dual;
```